# Using .ico files as icons when creating executables in DrRacket IDE

Tags: scheme, racket

I have a simple question. Whenever I create a stand-alone application from the DrRacket IDE, I want to use an .ico file as the icon for the file. The acceptable dimensions are 16x16, 32x32, or 48x48. However, whenever I attempt I attach an .ico files to use, DrRacket just creates the executable with the default DrRacket icon. Does anyone have any idea why this is occurring?

Answer (score 3):

[Raco](http://download.racket-lang.org/docs/5.0/html/raco/exe.html) contains a command line option to supply an .ICO file for the resulting executable.  See http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/exe.html:

```
raco exe -ico /path/to/icon.ico
```

Comment: This creates an executable correctly, but the desktop icon is still the default and not the one that I am trying to use. While this is a minor issue, it is annoying as I want all of the features to work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can hack the executable and put your own icon in there.  There are a number of utilities (some free) that can be used for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I got the same error, but I had one and I solved using .ICO files instead of .ico

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31259834)